# Is there a place to set the UINavigationBar's default color?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I am a new iOS developer working on a project that created by an ex-employee. Currently all the navigation bar is black, and I need to change them to the default blue color. So far I have figured out this line:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[[UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:0.33 brightness: 0.65 alpha:1.0] autorelease]];
```

It worked, but I don't think it's the right way to do it. I have created a new screen too and the color is blue, so I figure there must be a setting in some place. In the xib file the Top Bar is none, and we have this code in viewDidLoad

```
if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]; 
    }
    else {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    }
```

The question is: is there a place I can set the default color? or I have to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your Navigation Controller, you can set the color for the bar:

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: mainView];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor <whatever color you want>];
```

Or if you just want the default blue color:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
```

Comment: Use this if you want iOS 4 support, otherwise the new UIAppearance feature looks pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 5 you could use Appearence to do that

```
  [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

You can do this in you `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` , for example.

In the previous version of iOS you should make a Category on NavigationBar, and override it's drawing methods.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it the right way. The navigation bar can be shared between many ViewControllers when pushViewController has been used (e.g. when showing a detail view for an item in an UITableViewController).

iOS5 has a new UIAppearance feature for more detailed app-wide themeing that you might want to check out - http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

Answer (score 1):

To set the default color, use:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:nil];
```

To set a different color with gradient, use:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:hue/359.0f
                                                     saturation:saturation/100.0f
                                                     brightness:brightness/100.0f
                                                          alpha:alpha]];
```

Please note; hue, saturation, brightness and alpha are of type `float`.